Dashboard in Event driven design
Lets imagine we have several bounded contexts and they are all decoupled using messaging services (queues, message buses).
Some business process, lets say Order processing spans multiple bounded contexts.
For example, Order placed by the user is initially received, then validated, payment is processed, inventory adjusted, Order scheduled for delivery and finally Order gets into delivered state.
The EDA is implemented using choreography without central Manager.
Also, there is a dashboard which should, at each step, indicate the state of the order.
Now, because of the async nature of the process, previous state event (e.g. PaymentProcessed) might get to Dashboard boundee context after next state (e.g. ScheduledForDelivery).
How to handle this situation where Dashboard should always reflect the last state of the process?

What is a "bounded context" in this context?

"and they are all decoupled using messaging services" - Is that an assumption you're making from the design or is that something you're asserting? ...because components can still be tightly-coupled even when there's an intermediary in-betweeen them.

Where is the current state of an Order persisted? (don't say "in-memory" - that's not a persisrtance medium). Can't your dashboard just read this all from the production database?

"Now, because of the async nature of the process, previous state event (e.g. PaymentProcessed) might get to Dashboard boundee context after next state (e.g. ScheduledForDelivery)." - in that case the constraints to this problem (as you've described it) cannot be satisfied because you've just-said it's impossible to get the latest state for an Order.

@Dai Well, depends how you define 'latest'. You could reason about it that you don't allow that particular transition which would put Dashboard to previous state. That might be accomplished using state machine, e.g.

State od the Order is persisted in database.

Components must be decoupled for other rasons, behind this topic.

Apply the "never go back" principle. Let say that an Order has to go through the states state1, state2, state3 then state4. In your dashboard, put a little bit of logic to reject any message that would make an order to "go back". If you receive a state2 message for an Order that does not exist, create it in that state. If later you receive the state1 message for that same Order, reject it because you know state1 comes before state2.

Yeah, I had on mind something like that. Is there any downside to that approach?

None I can think of.

I had once a requirement about processes that remain stuck into a intermediate state. I've just added a date-time field for each state, and every time I received a message, I updated the appropriate field. That way, I could retrieve incomplete processes and define some business rules to raise alerts whenever a process does not reach the final state within a given time, or if some messages are lacking.
